# Updating an instance of a class that relies on an instance of another different class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am giving the Product Inventory Project at karan/Projects a try. I was able to achieve the basic outcomes required by this project shown below:

"Create an application which manages an inventory of products. Create a product class which has a price, id, and quantity on hand. Then create an inventory class which keeps track of various products and can sum up the inventory value."

However, I wanted to take this project one step further and be able to update any attribute for any product at any point in time.

```
# Product Inventory Project

class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, price, id, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.id = id
        self.quantity = quantity
        self._test = 0

    @property
    def prod_info(self):
        self._prod_info = (self.price, self.id, self.quantity, self._test)
        return self._prod_info

    @prod_info.setter
    def prod_info(self, val):
        self._prod_info = val

    @property
    def test(self):
        return self._test

    @test.setter
    def test(self, val):
        self._test = val


class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.productlist = []

    def add_product(self, products):
        self.products = products
        self.productlist.append(products.prod_info)

    def sum_of_products(self):
        self.product_sum =  sum([i[0] for i in self.productlist])
        return self.product_sum

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.sum_of_products())

apples = Product(1.00, 1234, 10)
oranges = Product(2.00, 4567, 10)

apples.test = 1234567

inventory = Inventory()
inventory.add_product(apples)
inventory.add_product(oranges)

print(inventory.productlist)
apples.test = 9435643
print(apples.prod_info)
print(inventory.productlist)
```

I get the following output from my print statements:

```
print(inventory.productlist) -> [(1.0, 1234, 10, 1234567), (2.0, 4567, 10, 0)]

print(apples.prod_info) -> (1.0, 1234, 10, 9435643)

print(inventory.productlist) ->[(1.0, 1234, 10, 1234567), (2.0, 4567, 10, 0)]
```

What I was hoping to achieve was to have the apples instance in the inventory instance update to the most current apples instance so that it prints the correct product information.